# How to resize when less than 768px in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resize, media-queries

```
  return (
    <ISO.OLayer className="main-body-content">
      <ISO.OResultBox autoHeight={true}>
        <ISO.ResultBoxNoBorder style={{ height: '100%' }}>
          <JqxSplitter
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            panels={[{ size: '35%' }, { size: '65%' }]}
            orientation={'horizontal'}
          >
            <div className="splitter_record">
              <JqxSplitter
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                panels={[{ size: '70%' }, { size: '30%' }]}
                orientation={'vertical'}
              >
          </JqxSplitter>
        </ISO.ResultBoxNoBorder>
      </ISO.OResultBox>
    </ISO.OLayer>
  );
}
```

React is my first time, so hard.
I tried to control the size width with css. But it didn't work.
I want to change
panels={[{ size: '70%' }, { size: '30%' }]}
orientation={'vertical'}
to
panels={[{ size: '100%' }, { size: '100%' }]}
orientation={'horizontal'}
when it is less than 768px